# How to set up a font style guide for any font?

Tags: typography, interface-design, font-size, adobe-xd, style-guide

I am working on a **mobile app** UI design in `Adobe XD`. Before starting the design I would like to setup a **font style guide**. What I have achieved so far is in the attached image. I am using a typeface named **Gilroy**. I wonder what is the best way to setup a font style guide for your design, using any font other than those fonts used in the ios/android design guidelines. I would like to know the step by step process for creating a font style guide when you start your UI design.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have made a pretty good job of it already. I'm not entirely sure what you are asking when you say the "best way".  Best is subjective. Whatever works for you is "best" for you.

Comment: I have made this using random values which I thought will look good in the design. But I was thinking what method do other professionals out there use inorder to achieve the right  values. I would like to know whether there is any proper method to follow, inorder to create a right size guide.

Comment: Maybe some other things you can add are guides for line spacing/leading, and perhaps whether lines of text should be justified, centred, left aligned, whether paragraphs should be indented or block, etc. The possibilities are endless. Maybe also consider reducing the number of size options, not so many heading or body text sizes. Keep it simple.

Comment: Agree that. But Is there any proper technique to find optimal font sizes ?

Comment: Not really - you are free to choose the sizes you want. It would very much depend on the font chosen, the layout, desired look, etc. There are just too many variables.